# Join two tables and display the data in in the third controller in cakephp

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I have three Models Quotation, QuotationItem and Job. 
My main Objective is to  do a left join for tables of Quotation and QuotationItem in the Job controller. I cannot achieve it because instead of QuotationItem ,the job table is being used in left join!

```
      $this->Job->unbindModel(
    array('belongsTo' => array('Quotation','QuotationItem')), true
);
            $options = array(
'fields' => array(
    'QuotationItem.id',
    'QuotationItem.Quot_id',
    'QuotationItem.item_sno',
    'QuotationItem.job_desc',
    'QuotationItem.selected_qty',
    'QuotationItem.paper_id',
    'QuotationItem.plate_id',
    'QuotationItem.design_id',
    'QuotationItem.ink_id',
    'QuotationItem.misel_id',
    'QuotationItem.plate_size',
    'QuotationItem.paper_size',
    'QuotationItem.paper_type',
    'QuotationItem.paper_gsm',
    'QuotationItem.plate_qty',
    'QuotationItem.paper_qty',
    'QuotationItem.ink_qty',
    'QuotationItem.plate_color',
    'QuotationItem.ink_color',
    'QuotationItem.ink_code',
    'QuotationItem.plate_price',
    'QuotationItem.paper_price',
    'QuotationItem.ink_price',
    'QuotationItem.design_price',
    'QuotationItem.plate_total',
    'QuotationItem.paper_total',
    'QuotationItem.ink_total',
    'QuotationItem.design_total',
    'QuotationItem.printing_cost',
    'QuotationItem.prepress_cost',
    'QuotationItem.design_cost',
    'QuotationItem.press_cost',
    'QuotationItem.folding_cost',
    'QuotationItem.binding_cost',
    'QuotationItem.block_cost',
    'QuotationItem.lamination_cost',
    'QuotationItem.uv_cost',
    'QuotationItem.stamping_cost',
    'QuotationItem.diecutting_cost',
    'QuotationItem.sewing_cost',
    'QuotationItem.perfectbind_cost',
    'QuotationItem.saddlestitch_cost',
    'QuotationItem.emboss_cost',
    'QuotationItem.cutting_cost',
    'QuotationItem.labor_charges',
    'QuotationItem.others',
    'QuotationItem.cost_total',
    'QuotationItem.total_item_sum',
    'QuotationItem.net_total',
    'QuotationItem.created',
    'QuotationItem.modified',
    'QuotationItem.status',
    'Quotation.Quot_id',
    'Quotation.job_item',
    'Quotation.customer_id',
    'Quotation.customer_name',
    'Quotation.customer_phone',
    'Quotation.customer_email',
    'Quotation.customer_address',
    'Quotation.salesperson',
    'Quotation.pay_terms',
    'Quotation.contact_id',
    'Quotation.status',
    'Quotation.discount',
    'Quotation.total',
    'Quotation.created',
    'Quotation.modified',
),
'joins' => array(

    array(

        'table' => 'quotation',
        'alias' => 'Quotation',
        'type' => 'left',
                    'conditions' => array('QuotationItem.Quot_id = Quotation.Quot_id'),
    )
),
'conditions' => array(
    '1',
));$data = $this->Job->find('all', $options);`
```

Comment: Why are you executing find on the Job model if you're not trying to find Jobs? What you appear to be looking to do is execute a find on Quotations which LEFT joins QuotationItem, is that correct?

Comment: Yeah thats the idea. But when I load the quotation model into the job  controller , it shows sql 42000 error. Table/alias not unique

Comment: Wot i am planning to do here is fetch the data from quotation and quotation items using join and then store it inside the job

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @Tim for making me understand about model and controller. I have found the answer to my Question. 
I used the join in my QuotationItem model since the QuotationItem belongs to Quotation  .

```
public $belongsTo = array(
    'Quotation' => array(
        'className' => 'Quotation',
        'foreignKey' => 'Quot_id',
        'type'=>'left',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    )
);
```

Then I declared `public $uses = array('Job','Quotation','QuotationItem');` in my jobs controller
after that in my add function I used

```
$quotationItem=$this->QuotationItem->find('all');

$this->set(compact( 'quotationItem'));
```

Finally I got my joins working

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the find on Quotation, not on Job. Models are tied to a table, think of them as one-in-the-same. You can't find something from a different table that has nothing to do with the Model you're executing the find function on.

If you're getting `sql 42000 error. Table/alias not unique` when loading a model, it's either already been loaded or you're trying to alias something with a name that's already been used for something else - which you can't do.

The simplest way to ensure you have access to all 3 Models from the Job Controller if you haven't grasped model associations well yet is to declare `public $uses = array('Job','Quotation','QuotationItem');` in your Job Controller.

Whatever way you go about getting access to Quotation aside, what you want to do is then:

```
$this->Quotation->find('all',array(
    'fields' => '*',
    'joins' => array(
        array(
            'table' => 'quotation',
            'alias' => 'Quotation',
            'type' => 'left',
            'conditions' => array(
                'QuotationItem.Quot_id = Quotation.Quot_id'
            )
        )
    )
));
```

Comment: Thank you @tim for providing me with the solution.. I will check it out tomorrow and get back to you .

Comment: Hi @Tim, can you expain to me where I should put the above code. I used the code in the add function of job controller.

Comment: That should be fine as long as you've made sure you have access to the Quotation model, as explained above.